# Facebook Ads Api : Remove users from Custom Audience does not have any effect to its matching size

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api, target-audience

I am using facebook python's ads api to add and remove user's emails from custom audience.

I have successfully added user's emails to audience using these lines of code (based on Facebook examples):

```
#Add users 
#users is a dataframe. I am creating a list of emails like this 
#['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com',....]

users_email_list = users['email'].tolist()
CustomAudience(audience_id).add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.email_hash, 
users_email_list)
```

I have successfully removed, but with no effect, user's emails from audience using these lines of code (based on Facebook examples):

```
#Remove users

CustomAudience(audience_id).remove_users(CustomAudience.Schema.email_hash,  
users_email_list)
```

I have included 100 different Facebook emails for this audience where I have 100% match. 
After adding users emails I am visiting facebook ads console (business.facebook.com) to inspect Custom Audience. There I can see that 100 rows have been added and the size indication is 100 (with Ready status-green). 
After I am running the second block of code to remove the users emails I have added. In facebook ads console I can see that 100 rows have been removed but even after waiting a couple of days size remains the same 100, with Status Ready - green. (I have tried this also with less than 100 emails)

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: are you removing all 100 email addresses or just one?

Comment: I am removing all 100 email at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted with Facebook's targeting team, the above method works. It takes a couple of days to be updated.